# Bluetooth HID module

Tags: bluetooth

I try to build custom controller and now searching for bluetooth hid module. Which BT HID module compatible with arduino? (not bluetooth serial)

List of some modules:

- BlueSMiRF HID - from sparkfun, expensive (based on rn-42, also available RN-42-EK evaluation board) ✔ compatible
- HM-10 bluetooth module - around $10 (aliexpress), based on cc2540 ht
  tp://www.ti.com/product/cc2540
- HC-05 Transceiver Module  - less $10, maybe supports HID after firmware upgrade(??)
- Bluegiga wt12
- Bluefruit EZ-HID from Adafruit ~$20 (suggested by [mwwalk](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/3715/3332)) ✔ compatible

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *(not bluetooth serial)*? Also, what's the objective of the question? All of those should be compatible with Arduino...

Comment: Module should support Human Interface Device protocol (HID), after connection to host system you can use it as keyboard/mouse etc, bluetooth serial port works like serial and if you want send keyboard signal you need additional software on computer (serial to hid)

Comment: Ahh, apologies I totally missed the whole HID thing... apologies again :)

Comment: The HM-10 is a BLE module incompatible with legacy bluetooth.  Some recent smartphones and other devices can talk both protocols, but be sure yours supports BLE (and for your intended usage) before you go with that option.  Also realize you need firmware for the module, either custom or a configuration of a factory firmware which meets your needs.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure from your question if you want just the module or a whole breakout board.  If the latter, try this from adafruit. It can very easily do his either as mouse or keyboard and is well documented and supported so I think this would be much easier to get running initially. http://www.adafruit.com/products/1535

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I would like to buy this item, unfortunately adafruit don't ship items to my country and don't accept payments from cards.

Comment: Anyway, I bought `Bluegiga wt12` (bare module) only for $12 from ebay and now making pcb. Bluegiga have very good website and a lot of useful documents.

Answer (score 3):

HC-05 HC-06 and, for example, RN-42 HID are the same looking on hardware design.

Only difference is in firmware.

For educational purposes you can dump firmware from RN42HID and flash HC-05/06 module and you've got a HID module.

The difference in costs of the HID modules is that CSR IDE costs $3000 per licence  + developer seat, and when someone invests in developing wants the incomes to come.

Byron's blog will guide you, you need a SPI programmer, but you can use Arduino as programmer/debugger. And you will need blueflash software to backup some info from Your module (calibration of crystal for example, and IDS/MAC/serial) than you can flash the RN firmware, and you have exact copy of RN, last thing is to restore the settings saved from your original firmware.

Just Google it, here is not much place to put all the data and images.

But yes it is possible.